# SQL sort specific column based on the value in another column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have data in following form, I want to sort the `balance` column based on the same value in `reference` column.

```
reference | balance        
----------------------
ADE       |    100
ADE       |     95
ADE       |     90
AVR       |     83
AQE       |     95
AQE       |     71
```

Result would look like as below

```
reference | balance        
----------------------
ADE       |     90
ADE       |     95
ADE       |    100
AVR       |     83
AQE       |     71
AQE       |     95
```

Comment: You may use a case expression within your order by clause to specify the order of references, or you could have a table/ CTE with the default references order you want and then do a join with your table to get that default order. Check this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/Ap99t31I

Answer (score 0):

You should first sort the table with reference column in ascending order and then with the balance column in ascending order. Please see the SQL query below to achieve the same

```
SELECT reference, balance
FROM your_table
ORDER BY reference ASC, balance ASC;
```

Comment: but this will change the sequence of the records. i dont want to make it ascending order for reference column (it should stay the same)

Comment: @unknown, this comment had to be clarified in your question, your question was closed as duplicate because you didn't clarify that in it.